# Trying to generate a Unique Invoice number

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am working on a "Job Site" workbook for my company. It will eventually take care of all the paperwork that is to be turned in at the end of a job. The old invoice that we were given simply used the invoice total as the "Ticket Number", but there are cases where that results in a duplicate ticket number.

So what I have done is used VBA to extract the 1st letter of each word in a customer's name using this code:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(rng As Range) As String
    Dim arr
    Dim I As Long
    arr = VBA.Split(rng, " ")
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
        Next I
    Else
        GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And affixed that to the beginning of invoice total. The result, however, leaves me with a decimal and the remaining change, which I would like to omit.

[image]

I haven't found a way to remove the decimal places, and I am not even sure if it possible now that the cell contains a word&value combination, but I figured this would be the place to ask.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: so I assume you have a formula in the worksheet that is concatenating the two together.  Can you add that to the question using [edit]?

Comment: Just as the answers below, but I have used named ranges. So `=GetFirstLetters(customer)&total`

Both of the answers provided work perfectly.. So thanks for that.

In my head I was thinking, that since it not a number value, I wouldn't be able to format it properly. It didn't cross my mind to format in the formula itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use INT() to get just the number without the decimal places:

```
=GetFirstLetters(A1)&INT(A2)
```

Where A1 has the name and A2 the total.

Comment: both ways shown work flawlessly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [FLOOR.MATH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/floor-math-function-c302b599-fbdb-4177-ba19-2c2b1249a2f5), for example with the function

```
=A1 & FLOOR.MATH(B1)
```

in cell C1, you could have

[image: Excel excerpt]

Comment: Your method worked flawlessly as well. Thanks for the input!